# The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, foreign-keys

I know there are lots of similar questions out there but none of them help me figure this out. I am simply trying to change the value of `Status` on a record in the WC_Inbox table to `Archived` from `Pending` but I am getting this error. The main reason I am asking here is because I don't understand how the foreign key has anything at all to do with the operation I am trying to perform.

#### WC_InboxController.cs

```
 // POST: WC_Inbox/Work/5
 // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Work([Bind(Include = "ID,EncovaID,EmployeeID,District,Org_Number,Hire_Date,Job_Title,Work_Schedule,Injury_Date,Injury_Time,DOT_12,Start_Time,Injured_Body_Part,Side,Missing_Work,Return_to_Work_Date,Doctors_Release,Treatment,Injury_Description,Equipment,Witness,Questioned,Medical_History,Inbox_Submitted,Comments,User_Email,Contact_Email,Specialist_Email,Optional_Email,Optional_Email2,Optional_Email3,Optional_Email4,TX_EROI_lag,Claim_Ruling,Injury_Type,TTD_Onset_Date,Restricted_RTW,Full_Duty_RTW,TTD_Award_notice,RTW_Notice_Carrier,Lost_Time_Start1,Lost_Time_End1,Lost_Time_Start2,Lost_Time_End2,Lost_Time_Start3,Lost_Time_End3,Status,HR_Comments,Add_User,Date_Added,HR_User,Date_Modified")] WC_Inbox wC_Inbox)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                wC_Inbox.HR_User = User.Identity.Name;
                wC_Inbox.Date_Modified = DateTime.Now;
                db.Entry(wC_Inbox).State = EntityState.Modified;
                try
                {
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
                {
                    foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
                    {
                        foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                        {
                            Trace.TraceInformation("Property: {0} Error: {1}", validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);
                        }
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.EmployeeID = new SelectList(db.Employees, "ID", "First_Name", wC_Inbox.EmployeeID);
            return View(wC_Inbox);
        }
```

#### Work.cshtml

```
@model HR_APP_V2.Models.WC_Inbox

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Work";
}

<h2>Work WC Inbox Form for @ViewBag.Name</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)
    @Html.Hidden("EmployeeID", (object)ViewBag.EmployeeID)
    @Html.Hidden("Add_User", (object)ViewBag.user)
    @Html.Hidden("Date_Added", (object)ViewBag.date)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.District, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.District, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "0025" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.District, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Org_Number, "Org Number", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Org_Number, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Org_Number, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Hire_Date, "Hire Date", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Hire_Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Hire_Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Job_Title, "Job Title", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Job_Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Job_Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Work_Schedule, "Work Schedule", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Work_Schedule, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Work_Schedule, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Injury_Date, "Injury Date", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Injury_Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Injury_Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Injury_Time, "Injury Time", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Injury_Time, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Injury_Time, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DOT_12, "DOT 12", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DOT_12)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DOT_12, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Start_Time, "Start Time", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Start_Time, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Start_Time, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Injured_Body_Part, "Injured Body Part", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Injured_Body_Part, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Injured_Body_Part, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Side, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Side, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Side, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Missing_Work, "Missing Work", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Missing_Work)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Missing_Work, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Return_to_Work_Date, "Return to Work Date", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Return_to_Work_Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Return_to_Work_Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Doctors_Release, "Doctors Release", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Doctors_Release)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Doctors_Release, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Treatment, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Treatment)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Treatment, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Injury_Description, "Injury Description", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Injury_Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Injury_Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Equipment, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Equipment, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Equipment, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Witness, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Witness, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Witness, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Questioned, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Questioned, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Questioned, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Medical_History, "Medical History", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Medical_History, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Medical_History, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Inbox_Submitted, "Inbox Submitted", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Inbox_Submitted)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Inbox_Submitted, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Comments, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Comments, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comments, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User_Email, "User Email", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User_Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User_Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Contact_Email, "Contact Email", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Contact_Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Contact_Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Specialist_Email, "Specialist Email", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Specialist_Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Specialist_Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Optional_Email, "Optional Email", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Optional_Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Optional_Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Optional_Email2, "Optional Email 2", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Optional_Email2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Optional_Email2, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Optional_Email3, "Optional Email 3", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Optional_Email3, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Optional_Email3, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Optional_Email4, "Optional Email 4", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Optional_Email4, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Optional_Email4, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <h2 style="text-align: center;">For HR staff use only</h2>
    <hr style="border:0px;border-top:1px solid grey;width:75%;" />

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EncovaID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EncovaID, "Encova ID", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EncovaID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TX_EROI_lag, "TX EROI Lag", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TX_EROI_lag, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TX_EROI_lag, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Claim_Ruling, "Claim Ruling", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Claim_Ruling, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Claim_Ruling, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Injury_Type, "Injury Type", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("Injury_Type", new List<SelectListItem>
            {
                new SelectListItem {Text = "MVA", Value="MVA"  },
                new SelectListItem {Text = "HEQ", Value="HEQ"  },
                new SelectListItem {Text = "Tree/Brush", Value="Tree/Brush"  },
                new SelectListItem {Text = "CTS", Value="CTS"  },
                new SelectListItem {Text = "HL", Value="HL"  },
                new SelectListItem {Text = "OP", Value="OP"  },
                new SelectListItem {Text = "OD NOC", Value="OD NOC"  }
            }, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TTD_Onset_Date, "TTD Onset Date", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TTD_Onset_Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TTD_Onset_Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Restricted_RTW, "Restricted RTW", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Restricted_RTW, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Restricted_RTW, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Full_Duty_RTW, "Full Duty RTW", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Full_Duty_RTW, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Full_Duty_RTW, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TTD_Award_notice, "TTD Award Notice", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TTD_Award_notice, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TTD_Award_notice, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RTW_Notice_Carrier, "RTW Notice Carrier", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RTW_Notice_Carrier, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RTW_Notice_Carrier, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Lost_Time_Start1, "Lost Time Start 1", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Lost_Time_Start1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Lost_Time_Start1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Lost_Time_End1, "Lost Time End 1", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Lost_Time_End1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Lost_Time_End1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Lost_Time_Start2, "Lost Time Start 2", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Lost_Time_Start2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Lost_Time_Start2, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Lost_Time_End2, "Lost Time End 2", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Lost_Time_End2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Lost_Time_End2, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Lost_Time_Start3, "Lost Time Start 3", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Lost_Time_Start3, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Lost_Time_Start3, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Lost_Time_End3, "Lost Time End 3", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Lost_Time_End3, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Lost_Time_End3, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Status, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("Status", new List<SelectListItem>
            {
                new SelectListItem {Text = "Pending", Value="Pending"  },
                new SelectListItem {Text = "Active", Value="Active"  },
                new SelectListItem {Text = "Archived", Value="Archived"  },
            }, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HR_Comments, "HR Comments", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HR_Comments, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HR_Comments, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

#### Employee.cs

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace HR_APP_V2.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    public partial class Employee
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Employee()
        {
            this.WC_Inbox = new HashSet<WC_Inbox>();
        }
    
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string First_Name { get; set; }
        public string Last_Name { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string Marital_Status { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> SSN { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Phone_Number { get; set; }
        public string Add_User { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date_Added { get; set; }
    
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<WC_Inbox> WC_Inbox { get; set; }
    }
}
```

#### WC_Inbox.cs

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace HR_APP_V2.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    public partial class WC_Inbox
    {
        public long ID { get; set; }
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public int? District { get; set; }
        public int? Org_Number { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime? Hire_Date { get; set; }
        public string Job_Title { get; set; }
        public int? Work_Schedule { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime? Injury_Date { get; set; }
        public string Injury_Time { get; set; }
        public bool DOT_12 { get; set; }
        public string Start_Time { get; set; }
        public string Injured_Body_Part { get; set; }
        public string Side { get; set; }
        public bool Missing_Work { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Return_to_Work_Date { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Doctors_Release { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Treatment { get; set; }
        public string Injury_Description { get; set; }
        public string Equipment { get; set; }
        public string Witness { get; set; }
        public string Questioned { get; set; }
        public string Medical_History { get; set; }
        public bool Inbox_Submitted { get; set; }
        public string Comments { get; set; }
        public string User_Email { get; set; }
        public string Contact_Email { get; set; }
        public string Specialist_Email { get; set; }
        public string Optional_Email { get; set; }
        public string Optional_Email2 { get; set; }
        public string Optional_Email3 { get; set; }
        public string Optional_Email4 { get; set; }
        public string Add_User { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime Date_Added { get; set; }
        public string EncovaID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> TX_EROI_lag { get; set; }
        public string Claim_Ruling { get; set; }
        public string Injury_Type { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> TTD_Onset_Date { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Restricted_RTW { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Full_Duty_RTW { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> TTD_Award_notice { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> RTW_Notice_Carrier { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Lost_Time_Start1 { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Lost_Time_End1 { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Lost_Time_Start2 { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Lost_Time_End2 { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Lost_Time_Start3 { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Lost_Time_End3 { get; set; }
        public string HR_Comments { get; set; }
        public string HR_User { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date_Modified { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
    
        public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In my SQL database the foreign key relationship on the Employee ID column has been set to `Cascade` as has been mentioned in similar posts.

What else could I try to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to  use a model in hidden fields since ViewBag data will not be posted back

```
 
  @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.EmployeeID)
  @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Add_User)
  @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Date_Added)
```

and remove binding from action since IMHO you don't need it

```
public ActionResult Work( WC_Inbox wC_Inbox)
```

Comment: Serge you always come to the rescue. Thank you again, that worked perfectly.

Comment: @GrillOwner69420 You are very welcome.